# youtube gdata getting the size of the video file

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using the youtube api and using python library gdata

i followed the documentation but doest seem the way out.
the question is -

```
  How do i get the size of the youtube video file without downloading it ?
```

i have seen the following url as well but it doesn't have the information about the size of the video

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{VIDEOID}?v=2&alt=jsonc

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the API for some time, but what I know is, you can't get video file size from the API.